# Moviepy video freezes when compositing a video

Tags: python, moviepy

```
import praw
import requests
import os
import glob
from moviepy.editor import *


files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\kaccm\Desktop\reddit_insta\*")
for f in files:
    os.remove(f)

print("Reddit_Downloader")
limit = int(input("Limit girin"))

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="LRO04bua6K8RjZ0dwcr-2w",
    client_secret="IWillNotPutSecretForSecurityPurposes",
    user_agent="testscript",
)

subreddit = reddit.subreddit(str(input("Subreddit girin ")))
hot = subreddit.hot(limit=100)

video_urls = []
for post in hot:
    if post.is_video and post.media["reddit_video"]["duration"] < 45 and len(video_urls) < limit:
        video_urls.append(post.media['reddit_video']['fallback_url'])

url_counter = 0
for url in video_urls:
    if ".mp4" in str(url):
        file_path = fr"C:\Users\kaccm\Desktop\reddit_insta\{url_counter}.mp4"
        response = requests.get(url)
        with open(file_path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        url_counter += 1
         video = VideoFileClip(file_path)
         text = TextClip("Deneme",fontsize=25,color="Black").set_position("bottom").set_duration(video.duration)
         final = CompositeVideoClip([video,text])
         final.write_videofile(file_path)
```

When I get the output the video is frozen.I tested it out and issue occurs when I composite the video and write it to the path

I tried to do composite the video and textvideo but after 1 seconds the video just freezes.But the the code works flawlessly if I don't composite the video.